# Is the geoToH3 function as pseudo-code available?

Tags: python, h3

Is there a (python) or pseudocode example of geoToH3 available? I just need this function and would like to avoid installing the library on my target environment (AWS GLUE, PySpark)

I tried to follow the [javascript implementation](https://github.com/uber/h3-js/blob/be3a542b237c2da36c2da2f14303a9d3e67aa734/lib/h3core.js#L548) but even that used C magic internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a pseudocode implementation that I'm aware of, but there's a fairly thorough explanation [in the documentation](https://uber.github.io/h3/#/documentation/core-library/walkthrough-of-geotoh3). Roughly:

- Select the icosahedron face (0-20) the point lies on (using point square distance in 3d space)
- Project the point into face-oriented IJK coordinates
- Convert the IJK coords to an H3 index by calculating the index digits at each resolution and setting the appropriate bits

The core logic can be found [here](https://github.com/uber/h3/blob/master/src/h3lib/lib/faceijk.c) and [here](https://github.com/uber/h3/blob/master/src/h3lib/lib/h3Index.c#L624). It's not trivial to implement - unless there's a strong reason to avoid installing, that would be the far easier and more reliable option.

Comment: I see, that code is some orders of magnitudes more complex than geohash/tiles. Thanks for pointing that out.